# Intersection of subvarieties in grassmannian space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

While working on a problem of differential topology I stumbled on a question of algebraic geometry that seems pretty basic, but that I'm unable to answer because I know very little algebraic geometry. I hope somebody could help:

It's known that if $X$ and $Y$ are (algebraic) subvarieties of $d$-dimensional (complex) projective space $P^d$ with complementary dimensions (i.e. $\dim X + \dim Y = d$) then $X \cap Y \neq \emptyset$ (in particular, any two curves in the projective plane $P^2$ always intersect).

My question is: Does this theorem hold if $P^d$ is replaced by the Grassmannian $G=G(m,n)$ (the set of $m$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$)?

In other words: If $X$, $Y$ are subvarieties of $G=G(m,n)$ whose dimensions sum to $\dim G(m,n) = m(n-m)$, does it follow that they have non-empty intersection?

In fact, in the situation I'm interested in, $Y$ is just a immersed smaller grassmannian $G(m-k,n-k)$. [More precisely, $Y$ is the set of $m$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$ that contain a given fixed $k$-dimensional subspace, where $k < m < n$.]

If the answer to the question is no (even for this particular $Y$), I pose a sharper question: What is the least $s=s(m,n)$ such that for any subvariety $X$ of $G$, if $\dim X + \dim Y \geq s$ (where $Y$ is as above) then $X \cap Y \neq \emptyset$?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a crash course on cohomology of the grassmannians, Schubert calculus, etc, I think I've found the answer to the second question: If the codimension of $X$ in $G_m(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is less than or equal to $m-k$ then $X$ should intersect the (Schubert cell) $Y$.

Luckily this should be sufficient for the application I have in mind.

Thanks for Francesco for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 21):

The answer to your first question is **no**.

In fact, consider the Grassmannian $G(2,4)$ of $2$-planes in $\mathbb{C}^4$, which has dimension $4$. It is isomorphic to the projective Grassmannian $\mathbb{G}(1,3)$ of lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$, and the Plücker embedding realizes it as a quadric hypersurface $X \subset \mathbb{P}^5$.

Now take a point $p$ and a plane $H$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ such that $p \notin H$.

Let $\Sigma_p$   be the set of lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ containing $p$ and let $\Sigma_H$ be the set of lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ lying in $H$.

Then under the Plücker embedding $\Sigma_p$ and $\Sigma_H$ are carried to two linear subspaces of dimension $2$ in $X$ such that

$\Sigma_p \cap \Sigma_H= \emptyset$.

Comment: Gah, too slow writing the same counterexample. Anyway the basic point is that the Betti numbers of projective space are all 1, but $b_4$ of G(2,4) is 2, with $\Sigma_p,\Sigma_H$ giving a basis.

Comment: Dear Allen, I think this is really a standard counterexample. I was just lucky to sit in front of my computer at the right moment :-)

Comment: Ok. I think I can reread this as follows (applying back the isomorphism):

Take a splitting $\C^4 = E \oplus F$ where $\dim E = 1$, $\dim F = 3$. Take $Y$ (resp. $X$) as the set of $2$-spaces of $\C^4$ that contain $E$ (resp. are contained in $F$). Then $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint and $\dim X + \dim Y = 2 + 2 = \dim G(2,4)$. 

Thank you very much.

Any idea about the second question?

Answer (score 19):

As Franscesco's answer shows, there is a standard counterexample to your problem. However, if you put some mild restrictions on the subvarieties, the answer is yes.

One of Hartshorne's old conjectures asks if the following is true:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are subvarieties of $Z$
>   with ample normal bundles $N_{X|Z}$,
>   $N_{Y|Z}$ and $\dim X+\dim Y=\dim Z$,
>   then $X$ and $Y$ have non-empty
>   intersection.

In $\mathbb{P}^n$ the above conditions on the normal bundles are automatic (since they are a quotient of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^n$, which is ample), but in the general case, the ampleness of the normal bundles is a natural requirement. Hartshorne's conjecture has been proved by Lubke for any homogeneous variety, so in particular for any Grassmannian. For the proof, see

[Martin Lübke, Beweis einer Vermutung von Hartshorne für den Fall homogener Mannigfaltigkeiten.](http://www.reference-global.com/doi/abs/10.1515/crll.1980.316.215), Crelles Journal, 1980.

The general Hartshorne's conjecture is however still open, although there is more evidence supporting it. For a survey, see the recent paper by Peternell: [Submanifolds with ample normal bundles and a conjecture of Hartshorne](http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1023)

Comment: Ah, this is interesting! In fact, by a result of Papantonopoulou, see
http://www.jstor.org/stable/2042706, the normal bundle of a smooth subvariety $X$ in the Grassmannian $\mathbb{G}(1,3)$ is not ample if and only if $X$ is a Schubert cycle. 